# Data structure for a one-dimensional spatial index

Tags: data-structures

I have a large number of objects each representing a numeric range (e.g. [1,3], [2,8], [3,3]).  I want to be able to rapidly query for all of the ranges overlapping a given range. This is the one-dimensional equivalent of standard 2D or 3D spatial indexes, such as R-trees.

For example:

```
Data = [0,1], [1,3], [2,8], [3,3], [5,9]
Query = [2,4]
Output = [1,3], [2,8], [3,3]
```

I'd like adding items to the structure or removing items from it to usually run in O(log N), and for searching the structure to also usually be O(log N).

Is there a good fit from well-understood standard data structure?

Answer (score 3):

An [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) comes to mind, which is: (description from Wikipedia, image from [here](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/JamesStewart/378notes/22intervals/))

> A tree with each node storing:
>
> - A center point
> - A pointer to another node containing all intervals completely to the left of the center point
> - A pointer to another node containing all intervals completely to the right of the center point
> - All intervals overlapping the center point sorted by their beginning point
> - All intervals overlapping the center point sorted by their ending point
>
> [image]

It allows for `O(log n + m)` interval intersection queries, where `m` is the number of intersecting intervals.

You'll have to look at either of the sites for more details regarding construction and querying.